# I do not know how to fix this simple issue on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to execute my first macro and I got an error whose I don't find any answer on the net.

Can you help me please?

My message of error: Error Automation

When I'm trying to debug the line is in yellow `Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")`

This is my code:

```
Sub export_données_dans_word()
Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Dim worddoc As Word.Document

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")
Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("Users/iMacdeMax/Documents/Test Word Macro.docx")

worddoc.Bookmarks("signet2").Range.Text = Range("a1").Value

worddoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "_" & ".pdf", ExportFormat:= _
    17, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    0, Range:=0, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=0, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=0, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    
worddoc.Close Savechanges:=False

wordapp.Quit


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate references associated with your module to be able to call `Word`?  Please state your specific error message/code.

Comment: Are you sure that Word is (properly) installed on the computer you run the code? Even if Excel looks to be installed... Can you manually open Word application?

Comment: Hi, thanks both of you for your comment. @FaneDuru i dont know what you mean by "manually open Word application" im sorry... i dug a little bit more on the subject and i found that this problem may come from the fact im using a Mac...

Comment: @Cyril my message of error is "Erreur d'exécution "2146959355 (80080005)"" Erreur Automation

Comment: Since you already have a reference to Word (`... As Word.Application`) try to new-it up to see if that works: `Set wordapp = New Word.Application`

Comment: hi @KostasK., thanks for your message. i replaced Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application") by Set wordapp = New Word.Application but i got the same error message ...

Comment: @guyestragon in some minimal searching, this error code appears tied to opening up other Office applications in general, whereas the only two resolutions I have found indicated that the correct references be used.  Verify which References you have selected for your specific module, whereas we would be expecting a MicroSoft Office Object Library of some sort (16,0 etc.).